# Codes unable to execute VBA Excel

Tags: vba, excel

```
Sub abc()
    Dim lrow As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set ws = ActivsheetWorksheets("Completed")

    Dim strFormulas(1 To 3) As Variant

    lrow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    With ws
        .Range("Y2:Z" & lrow).FillDown
    End With

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Completed")
        strFormulas(1) = "=(N2-A2)+(R2-O2)+(V2-S2)"
        strFormulas(2) = "=IFERROR(Y2/L2,Y2)"
        .Range("Y2:Z2").Formula = strFormulas
    End With
End Sub

Sub bcd()
    Dim lrow As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set ws = Worksheets("Follow-up")

    Dim strFormulas(1 To 3) As Variant

    lrow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    With ws
        .Range("Y2:Z" & lrow).FillDown
    End With

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Follow-up")
        strFormulas(1) = "=(N2-A2)+(R2-O2)+(V2-S2)"
        strFormulas(2) = "=IFERROR(Y2/L2,Y2)"
        .Range("Y2:Z2").Formula = strFormulas
    End With
End Sub
```

Can the above code be simplified into one. It is working fine but the thing is I need to simplify the code since I have to call it in a UserForm. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Do you just want them in one sub?

Comment: Paul, It doesn't seem that there is any changes made to the code. can you please let me know what the exact changes that are..

Comment: Yes Paul I want it under one Sub.

Answer (score 0):

If the code just needs to be moved into one, you can just create different variables. Although I do not see any major advantage of this.

```
Sub oneSub()
    Dim completeRow As Long, followRow As Long
    Dim wsComplete As Worksheet, wsFollow As Worksheet

    Set wsComplete = Worksheets("Completed")
    Set wsFollow = Worksheets("Follow-up")

    Dim strFormulas(1 To 3) As Variant

    completeRow = wsComplete.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    followRow = wsFollow.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    wsComplete.Range("Y2:Z" & completeRow).FillDown
    wsFollow.Range("Y2:Z" & followRow).FillDown

    strFormulas(1) = "=(N2-A2)+(R2-O2)+(V2-S2)"
    strFormulas(2) = "=IFERROR(Y2/L2,Y2)"

    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Completed").Range("Y2:Z2").Formula = strFormulas
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Follow-up").Range("Y2:Z2").Formula = strFormulas
End Sub
```

IMVHO Calling `Sub ABC` then `Sub BCD`, is same as `Sub oneSub`. Not much difference

Comment: No Paul  It wans't working fine for me... the codes didn't get copied to the next cell most of the time. Thank you for the Quick Response.